# Online Merchandising using Umbraco

Tags: paypal, umbraco, shopping-cart, add-on

I need to build a website using asp.net + sql server for sports merchandise business where the requirement is to display and sell merchandise internationally.

After some research I have decided to use Umbraco to build the website.

However I don't know what else would I need to purchase for this website like paypal plug-in, shopping cart, hosting space(go daddy?) etc

I have no experience in Umbraco or online merchandising so need some guidance here.

Thank You!
Arshya

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would never suggest that someone *not* use Umbraco as I personally think it is awesome, but I would ask why you chose Umbraco and not a 'dedicated' .Net ecommerce platform?

There is a package available for Umbraco called [uCommerce](http://www.ucommerce.dk/en/products.aspx) which has fantastic reviews, and there is a free version although it has certain key restrictions, like marketing aspects and the multi-language/multi-currency version has an annual charge. However if you are new to Umbraco but not to .Net it may be better looking at something like [nopCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com) which is free and open source.

Umbraco is a fantastic CMS and allows for the most flexible of site creation - but that is what it is, a site creation tool. nopCommerce is an out of the box ecommerce application that provides you a pre-built shopping website and administration area.

The only downside to nopCommerce is that it's CMS features aren't brilliant. By that I mean although you can create non-shopping pages, you can't create bespoke page/content structures in the same way you can in Umbraco.

Either way, before developing in anger I would suggest checking what your requirements and priorities actually are. Do you want a CMS with ecommerce features, or a ecommerce platform with CMS features?

**Update:**

Since writing this I have used an Umbraco package called uWebshop which is full-featured but slow, buggy and difficult to extend as the documentation as lacking. It is open source so I was able to delve and locate various extension points but it had too many bugs and the project was ultimately shelved.

There is another Umbraco package available called [Merchello](http://merchello.com/), again open source, which I am hearing very good things about and the documentation looks quite useful.

Comment: I would say I want an eCommerce platform with CMS features. But one of the things I should mention is that my client has already done the design in HTML and is adamant on having the same design. Does nopCommerce allow html editing like other CMS?

Comment: +1 Good answer - I'll use the "Do you want a CMS with ecommerce features, or a ecommerce platform with CMS features" line myself from now on!

Comment: I checked the CMS part of nopCommerce and I think it would satisfy my requirement of content management. I will show it to my client and finalize.

Answer (score 2):

Umbraco is a good CMS - the online starter videos will be useful (http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials)

I've played around with nopcommerce and it seemed a decent platform - I deployed ucommerce and it is a good package that is well integrated with the Umbraco way of working.  If you are used to Umbraco then including ucommerce functionality is a breeze.

If you go with ucommerce one gotcha that I have found is that the marketing foundation is not available in the free version - which means that you can't use the discounting and voucher concepts.  For a genuine shop that is likely to use discounting, sales, promotions etc to knock money off the RRP you will probably need to consider a paid version of ucommerce.

Comment: +1 Informative. But you didn't say why you chose UCommerce over NOPCommerce?